# what is the purpose of second argument in PKZIP CRC32()?

Tags: crc32, pkzip

I am trying to find a way of improving the attack PKZIP encryption but some things aren't clear and for today its this one:

```
key0 = crc32 ( key0, pt );
```

This is the CRC32 i know as standard it takes one argument:

```
#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL 0xEDB88320L

uint32_t crc32(const uint8_t *data, size_t length) {
    uint32_t crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            if (crc & 1) {
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ CRC32_POLYNOMIAL;
            } else {
                crc >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return ~crc;
}
```

It's not just me but [zipcrack](http://www.bokler.com/bokler/zipcrack.txt) also found Appnote misleading.

What is the purpose of `pt` in the expression, all the sources i have seen they either have data and its length as the 2 arguments, Or does it mean `crc32(key0+pt);`.
My problem is not with definitions but understanding the use an extra argument as you can see from the above code we already have 2 inputs to `crc32()` regardless of size, why would it be `crc32(data,len,chr)`, if i were to add that to the above code what would be the use of `char` in the function, That is my problem and i hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

From the appnote you got that from:

> Where crc32(old_crc,char) is a routine that given a CRC value and a
> character, returns an updated CRC value after applying the CRC-32
> algorithm described elsewhere in this document.

Comment: That's vague still, i still don't understand

Comment: That does not answer the question at all but it just repeats the same confusion

Comment: It's not vague at all. The data is one character. A character is one byte. The length of one byte is 1.

Comment: the question is a programming question about crc32 using 2 arguments of which i assume we all know that the first one is the message but what is the second one for, its sole purpose

Comment: to me it seems as programmers of PKZIP and others supporting it are afraid of something, so they made documentation vague and confusing

Comment: What? The first argument to the `crc32()` referenced in your question, as well as to the crc32() in zlib, as well as any other usable CRC routine, is the running CRC. It is an _n_-bit unsigned integer, where _n_ is the number of bits in the CRC, e.g., 32. As stated in the quote in my answer: "given a CRC value". The second argument in your question is a single byte. You need to read the words. All of the words. The second and third arguments in zlib's `crc32()` are the address of the message bytes, and the number of message bytes.

Comment: Many have read the documentation from PKWare and the RFCs describing deflate, gzip, and zlib, and have had no problem understanding them and writing code to implement them. They are neither vague nor confusing, with the proper background. You might consider the possibilty that you're the problem, not the documentation.

Comment: either way the answer should be like, ***given the crc32_old which is 32 bit number and a char which is 8 bit number as the second argument the CRC32 function will use argument 1 to do this and argument 2 to do this and that*** but instead you quote APPNOTE which i still fail to understand, why don't you answer correctly and clearly and by the way, yes i am the problem that is why i am here isn;t it?

Comment: I did answer clearly. Yes, it is assumed that you know what a CRC is by this point in the document, that the "32" means the number of bits in the CRC, and that you know what a character is. That is entirely reasonable background to expect. Are you seriously claiming that you are programming in C, and you did not already know what a char is? The document would be five times as long if all those had to be spelled out every. single. time. Lastly, I don't know what you mean by "do this".